# When changing the default browser for LiveServer on VSCode, how to input path of Brave Browser app on Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

I would like the LiveServer in VSCode to open up with Brave Browser. It does not list in the extension settings as a browser.

I tried going through the `settings.json` file and the following:

```
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": ""
```

How can I direct this line to the browser?

Easy to do with Windows, but I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "Brave Browser"
```